# Color different regions of graph (tikz)

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I would like to color the 6 different regions of a graph, delimited by curves, with different colors. It seems like I can only color one area at a time. This works to color one region:

```
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick       = {5,7},
    xticklabels = {$\hat{z}_1$,$\hat{z}_2$},
    ytick       = {4},
    yticklabels = {$\hat{b}_w$},
    samples     = 160,
    domain      = 0:10,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
  ]
  % path of axis
  \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  % Plot 1
  \addplot[name path=A, black, no markers, domain=0:5] {4};
  % FILL
  \addplot[blue] fill between[of=A and xaxis, soft clip={domain=0:5}];
    \addplot[name path=B thick,dashed,black] coordinates {(5, 0) (5, 10)};
   \addplot[name path=C thick,dashed,black] coordinates {(7, 0) (7, 10)};
   \addplot[name path=D thick,black] coordinates {(5,4) (7, 5)};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

But if I add another line for fill between, for example:

```
\addplot[red] fill between[of=D and xaxis, soft clip={domain=5:7}];
```

I get the error: illegal unit of measure and the graph won't compile.
Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't included your preamble in your code snippet, your code isn't a true minimal working example. As a result, your error about an illegal unit of measure is *unrelated to your problem with `fillbetween`*, and it must have occurred due to something else in your document.

The following code compiles without errors and provides the effect you want:  two filled regions with boundaries defined by two curves. The error in your code is that you did not include a comma after `name path=D` which meant PGFPlots thought the name of the path was `D thick` rather than just `D`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick       = {5,7},
    xticklabels = {$\hat{z}_1$,$\hat{z}_2$},
    ytick       = {4},
    yticklabels = {$\hat{b}_w$},
    samples     = 160,
    domain      = 0:10,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
  ]
  % path of axis
  \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  % Plot 1
  \addplot[name path=A, black, no markers, domain=0:5] {4};
  \addplot[name path=B, thick,dashed,black] coordinates {(5, 0) (5, 10)};
  \addplot[name path=C, thick,dashed,black] coordinates {(7, 0) (7, 10)};
  \addplot[name path=D, thick,black] coordinates {(5,4) (7, 5)};
  % FILL
  \addplot[blue] fill between[of=A and xaxis, soft clip={domain=0:5}];
  \addplot[red]  fill between[of=D and xaxis, soft clip={domain=5:7}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A red region and blue region. The red region is bound by curve A and the x-axis, and the blue region is bound by curve D and the x-axis.]